# How can I get the list of indices an associative array has?

Tags: awk, key, associative-array

I have an associative array in `awk`, and I can iterate over the *values* of the array using (e.g.) `for (v in ARRAY) ...`.

However I want to iterate over the *indices* (keys) of the array instead.

Unfortunately I did not find the function how to do that.
(In Perl I'd use `keys %hash` for that)

Comment: Sorry, I had actually mixed keys and values when initializing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an associative array in `awk`, and I can iterate over the
> values of the array using (e.g.) for `(v in ARRAY) ...`.

As far I as know it will do iterate over keys, consider following example

```
awk 'BEGIN{arr["a"]=1;arr["b"]=2;arr["c"]=3}END{for(i in arr){print i}}'
```

output

```
a
b
c
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*